# Converting Powershell Script to Logicapps part 2

Tags: powershell, azure-logic-apps

I've managed the http requests as per Joey's earlier advice (which I used for the logout part).  How do I do this part of the code in logic apps?  Including the rest of the script for context.

```
<code>
$Grid.Payload | where {$_.PR_OWN -eq "SC-CO-001"} | Select-Object -Property PR_SNAM, PR_OWN, PR_NAME, 
PR_ADD4, PR_TENR, PR_USER1 | Export-Clixml -Path "C:\Test\API\XML_Sample.xml"
$Grid.Payload | Select-Object -Property PR_SNAM, PR_OWN, PR_NAME, PR_ADD4, PR_TENR, PR_USER1 | Format-
```

Table -AutoSize

```
<pre>
#Core Parameters
$baseuri = "https://test"
$header = @{
"Accept" = "text/json"
"Content-Type" = "text/json"
}
$G_header = @{"Accept" = "text/json"}
#Login
Write-Output "Login ..."
$uri_login = $baseuri + "SPDEDJSONSERVICE.LOGIN"
$body_login = @{"method"="login";"username"="qqq";"password"="qqq"} | ConvertTo-Json
$Conn = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post $uri_login -Headers $header -Body $body_login
$SessionID = $conn.sessionID

#This is where we would code the data extraction
Write-Output "Gathering Data ..."
$uri_DefGrid = $baseuri + "SPDEDMHAPI.GRIDGET"
$body_DefGrid =   

 @{"sessionID"=$SessionID;"FORMAT"="payload";"GRIDID"="PROP";"GRIDVIEW"="1";
"FROM"=0;"HITS"=100;"PROFILE" 
=@(@{"PR_USER1"="GENERATED";"PR_NAME"="G*"});"ORDERBY"="PR_DATESOLD"} | ConvertTo-Json
$Grid = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post $uri_DefGrid -Headers $header -Body $body_DefGrid
$Grid.Payload | where {$_.PR_OWN -eq "SC-CO-001"} | Select-Object -Property PR_SNAM, PR_OWN, 
PR_NAME, PR_ADD4, PR_TENR, PR_USER1 | Export-Clixml -Path "C:\Test\API\XML_Sample.xml"
$Grid.Payload | Select-Object -Property PR_SNAM, PR_OWN, PR_NAME, PR_ADD4, PR_TENR, PR_USER1 | 
Format-Table -AutoSize

#Logout
Write-Output "Logging Out ..."
$uri_logout = $baseuri + "SPDEDJSONSERVICE.LOGOUT"
$body_logout = @{"method"="logout";"sessionID"=$SessionID} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post $uri_logout -Headers $header -Body $body_logout
<code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `$Grid.Payload | where {$_.PR_OWN -eq "SC-CO-001"} | Select-Object -Property PR_SNAM`

As I do not have your sample data, I use postman send request with below body:

```
{
    "list": [{"author": "Dan Brown", "isbn": "123456", "title": "Digital Fortress","name":"aaa"},
             {"author": "JK Rowling", "isbn": "234567", "title": "Harry Potter","name":"aaa"}]
}
```

1.Add body into `When a HTTP request is received` to generate schema.

2.Add compose to get the Array.

3.Use `Condition` with `outputs('compose')['list'][0]['name']` is eq to aaa to achieve `where` attribute.

4.Use `Select` of `Data Operations` to achieve `select` attribute.

The whole steps as below:

[image]
[image]

Comment: It wouldn't take the http request as that is a trigger rather than an action.  I therefore used parse json to achieve what I wanted.